# Is there some synchronization object that can be signaled/nonsignalled plus a value?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I want to block a thread until some action completes, but I don't just want signaled/non-signaled. If possible I'd like to block then examine the value and take appropriate action. All of this wrapped up into one object. AutoReset and ManualReset don't make it.

Comment: It looks like `lock(syncroot) { /* examine value */ /* do something */ }` wouldn't satisfy you. Could you elaborate more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm looking for a threading object that will allow me to block until signaled, then be tested for a specific value if true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a Task and a Wait?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608.aspx

Comment: Actually this would have been the way to do it fron the beginning, but presently would entail more work then just constructing my own object out of autoreset...thanks for the heads up..